# mask.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: v_fun is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, node.js

Estou utilizando um script JS para personalizar máscaras em inputs dentro de formulários. Um arquivo `mask.js` está sendo carregado nas páginas, contendo as seguintes funções:

```
function mascara(o,f){
    v_obj=o
    v_fun=f
    setTimeout(() => {
        v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
    },1)        
}
function cep(v){
    v=v.replace(/D/g,"")                //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/^(\d{5})(\d)/,"$1-$2") //Esse é tão fácil que não merece explicações
    return v

}
```

Um input:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cep">CEP do Endereço</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control cep" id="cep" name="cep" 
         placeholder="00.000-000" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

E um script no final da página para relacionar o input à função:

```
$('.cep').attr("onkeypress", "mascara(this, cep)")
$('.cep').attr("maxlength", "9")
```

Porém eu recebo o erro:

> "Uncaught TypeError: v_fun is not a function
> at mask.js:5",

sendo a linha 5:

```
v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
```

Não consigo encontrar o erro. O mais interessante é que o mesmo script funciona em outra página perfeitamente. Ao usar o `console.log(v_fun)` dentro da função `mascara`, na página que funciona corretamente o retorno é:

```
f cep(v){
v=v.replace(/D/g,"")                //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
v=v.replace(/^(\d{5})(\d)/,"$1-$2") //Esse é tão fácil que não merece explicações
return v
```

Porém na página que não funciona o retorno é igual ao componente html que o chamou:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control cep" id="cep" name="cep" placeholder="00.000-000" required="" onkeypress="mascara(this, cep)" maxlength="9">
```

Comment: Tenta mudar o nome da função e a passagem de parametro para `aplicarCEP`

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo claro de como ficaria?

Comment: Na verdade não vejo modo mais claro de dizer

Comment: @Sorack Eu consegui resolver com sua solução, MUITO obrigado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que quando você relaciona `cep` no `onkeypress`, o navegador interpreta como sendo o `input` com o `id` `cep`.

Altere a função `cep` para `aplicarMascaraCEP`:

```
...
function aplicarMascaraCEP(v){
...
```

E a chamada:

```
...
$('.cep').attr("onkeypress", "mascara(this, aplicarMascaraCEP)")
...
```

Comment: Era exatamente este o problema